# adding other content in top and bottom of MySurfaceView

Tags: android, layout, admob, surfaceview

I am designing an android application contain MySurfaceView includes a Canvas to draw images in a thread running through the application,

(layout is default main.xml which create with project)

but i have to add a bar/textView in the top and add an AD in the botton of the screen.
then how can i do this ?

my declaration is like this :

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mySurfaceView = new MySurfaceView(this);
    setContentView(mySurfaceView);              
}
```

May be my given information is not enough to understand the situation, so if you find any obscurity in my question please ask me

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm, one possibility is that you could just put it inside of a RelativeLayout or something similar? This assumes that you don't want to just define it in the xml which would probably look cleaner. The code would probably look something like this (you can definitely make it more efficient/just use a LinearLayout, I just threw down the first thing that came into my head):

```
  RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);
  RelativeLayout.LayoutParams paramsTop =
          new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                                          RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
  // Add the textView to the top
  paramsTop.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP, RelativeLayout.TRUE);

  TextView textView = new TextView(this);
  textView.setText("Hello World");
  // Give them id's since we need to position relative to one another
  textView.setId(1);
  layout.addView(textView, paramsTop);


  AdView adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, INSERT_ADMOB_ID_HERE);
  adView.setId(2);
  RelativeLayout.LayoutParams paramsBottom =
      new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                      RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
  // Add the adView to the bottom
  paramsBottom.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM, RelativeLayout.TRUE);

  layout.addView(adView, paramsBottom);
  AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest();
  adRequest.addTestDevice(AdRequest.TEST_EMULATOR);
  adView.loadAd(adRequest);


  SurfaceView view = new SurfaceView( this );
  view.setId(3);
  RelativeLayout.LayoutParams paramsMiddle =
          new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                                          RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

  // Add the surfaceView in between the textView and the adView
  paramsMiddle.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, textView.getId());
  paramsMiddle.addRule(RelativeLayout.ABOVE, adView.getId());
  layout.addView(view, paramsMiddle);

  setContentView(layout);
```

Comment: Works perfectly and exactly what i was searching for. Thank you very much.

Comment: another question based on this layout : if i want to show an image in the section of ad (with same banner size) until the ad is not loaded or by default the image will show and when the ad appear it will overlap the image how can it possible ?